# Prevent VS2017 from connecting to SQL database

Tags: dialog, visual-studio-2017, database-connection

I am working on a ASP.NET MVC project in Visual Studio.

Since today I see am seeing every now and then
a dialog window "Connect to SQL Server" that uses `{0}` as user name:

[image]

I always click `Cancel` as the user name is just a place holder. It is read - as the rest of the database configuration - from `Web.config`.

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev15.query?appId=Dev15IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(vs.sqlconnectionpromptdialog);k(DevLang-TSQL)&rd=true) just states:

> This dialog box appears when specific access permission is required
> for the current database process.

I believe I do not need this access. How can I prevent Visual Studio from showing this dialog?

PS: I do not want to remove the configuration from `Web.config` as it is needed by my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little debugging, it turned out that it was the [awesome Meene VS Tools 2017 extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BillMenees.MeneesVSTools2017) which caused this problem. Specifically, the `Enable tasks provider` option. Just disabling it helped to get rid of the nasty dialog. Maybe one could also add the `Web.config` to the `Excluded file name patterns` to fix the problem. Since I do not use the tasks, I did not try though.

Comment: Same problem with VS2019 even though ``tasks provider`` was disabled (by default). Enabling it, restarting VS, then disabling it again fixed the problem